# Best website to learn entry level Javascript?

Tags: javascript

What are the best websites to learn entry level Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screw w3schools ... seriously.

Head to the yahoo developer network, and learn real js.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/

And learn JS from the Crockford videos. THAT will save you time.

Comment: I don't think you're going to earn lots of respect here by saying "Screw w3schools"

Comment: No, I'm sorry, videos alone are simply not a good way to learn ANY language.

Comment: That's funny looking back on these comments now, now that there are tons of teaching sites online now, and all use videos, and w3 schools still has a bad reputation :)

Answer (score 8):

[www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) has a lot of information on Javascript and DOM.  They even have an online tutorials/examples that allow you to modify the example and re-run it to try out your new Javascript skills.

**Note:** Not everything there is mistake-free.  It's pretty useful, nonetheless.  For an alternative opinion, see http://w3fools.com.

Comment: w3schools, notepad (or notepad++) and a browser.

Comment: check this site http://w3fools.com

Comment: @kracekumar - I'm aware of that site, and while they have some valid points, I still find w3schools pretty useful as a quick reference.

Comment: @tvanfosson : Fine, nice to see w3fools in Note , I salute your spirit.

Answer (score 3):

Code Academy is a great website to learn Javascript.

http://www.codecademy.com/

Comment: Yes, CodeCademy is a good start. However, it's not very big yet (they didn't expect to get 200,000 users in 3 days - [seriously!](http://techcrunch.com/2011/08/22/codecademy-surges-to-200000-users-2-1-million-lessons-completed-in-72-hours/)). It's a good place to get started, but it won't last to long. As others have mentioned, W3Schools is also good (and more reputable); try that when you finish CA.

Answer (score 2):

[www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) has great tutorials and [www.jslint.com](http://www.jslint.com) will help you learn the best practices (and save a few headaches).

Answer (score 1):

[Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/) is a great website for books, articles, and blogs for everything web-related. It also has very active discussion forums.

Answer (score 0):

Websites are good but I recommend a good, solid book to have on-hand.  Simply Javascript (ISBN 0-9802858-0-1) is an excellent book by Site Point. Others are Head First Javascript on O'Reilly, and DOM Scripting on Friends of ED (If manipulating browser UI is what you're looking for)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a web site recently about developing GUI's in java, which is something I wanted to learn and found this site ( http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/guidebook/? ) After a few hours of reading and studding, I learned how to develop my first GUI, which is a code pad for security using a four digit int string to open it. The site is very easy to understand and the author gives you great code example to go by. I know there are easier ways to develop GUI's but for now I just wanted to get a basic understaning of them, and that is what this site does. It teaches you about JPanels, JLabels, and everything else you need to know to make a nice GUI. Since I started to learn Java, I found it best to use different sites, as I haven't found one single site that can teach you everything.

Answer (score 0):

[**Introduction to JavaScript**](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/introduction)

Answer (score -4):

You should just skip all the basics and study the jQuery API.

Comment: That was some pretty lame advise dude.

Comment: Apparently nobody gets sarcasm.